# WCF service library project can't find reference to other project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have two projects in my solution: MyApp.Domain and MyApp.WebService. MyApp.WebService is a WCF service library.

I want to use some utility functions from MyApp.Domain. So in MyApp.WebService, I added a reference to MyApp.Domain.

Intellisense picked it up just fine, it recognized the function I need to call. But when I build the solution, I get this error:

**The type or namespace name 'Domain' does not exist in the namespace 'MyApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

at `using MyApp.Domain.Utility;`

What's going wrong here?

Comment: What type of project is MyApp.Domain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure both are using the same profile... if one is using the client profile you could be getting this error.... also if the referenced assembly has some references in it to other assemblies you may need to include them in the project as well.  If that doesn't get it make sure both have the same setting for 32 vs 64 bit...

GL

Comment: So I looked at the warning messages, and it says it couldn't resolve the assembly because Domain relied on System.Web and System.Web.Abstractions. But when I try to add a reference to those two assemblies to my WebService project, .NET can't find them.

Comment: right click on your project... then click properties... find where it says you are using "client profile" and switch it to not use the "client profile" then you will be able to do this..

Comment: My problem was different TargetFrameworks between the two projects. the WCF project was building to .NET451 while the MODEL layer was building to .NET452

Answer (score -1):

Remove WCF Service project from Solution and build solution. After building solution, add WCF project again. Issue will be resolved.