# Adding Class Library Reference to WCF Service Library

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on my first web service, and I'm having trouble referencing another class library I have in my solution inside of my web service. Here is that service:

```
using MyDomain;

namespace WebServices
{
    public class AutomatedLogin : IAutomatedLogin
    {
        public Guid GetToken(string email)
        {
            //Code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

When I add a reference to `MyDomain` inside my WCF Service Library, intellisense recognizes the reference, but when I rebuild my solution, the compiler throws the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'MyDomain' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone tell me why the compiler is ignoring the `MyDomain` reference when I try to rebuild my solution?

Comment: Are you adding a reference within the project as well?  Or just in your class?

Comment: @Brian Within the WebServices project, yes. Within the MyDomain project, no.

Comment: you need to add the reference to your project

Comment: there you go i was late! Nevermind. you got the solution

Comment: What happens when you try and access a member in the `MyDomain` class?

Comment: @Brian Intellisense works as expected, and no errors are thrown until I try to build. After I build, Intellisense quits working, and the only way to get it working again is to remove and add the reference to the project.

Comment: And by "quits working", I mean that intellisense doesn't recognize `MyDomain` or any of it's members.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF service library project can't find reference to other project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060701/wcf-service-library-project-cant-find-reference-to-other-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a similar question:
[WCF service library project can't find reference to other project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060701/wcf-service-library-project-cant-find-reference-to-other-project?rq=1)

I changed the project's **target framework** from `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` to `.NET Framework 4` which seems to have fixed the compiling issue.